# How can I load images on my webpage using mongodb/mongoose?

Tags: image, node.js, mongodb

When a user loads my webpage, I want to load in images just like any other website would, except that the images are stored in my mongo database. I am using mongoose/schemas if it matters. All of my images are small (under 1mb), so I have no need for gridfs. So essentially, when I receive a get request on my server for an image, how can I return an image that I have stored in my mongodb?

Comment: What did you try yet? Your question is too general!

Comment: @heinob ...what? It isn't too general. I am literally just asking how to retrieve an image stored in mongo.

Comment: get image out of database -> encode base64 (if it is not yet) -> send to client -> put IMAGE into an <image src=base64;...> tag